# psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory, allowing communication over TCP/IP, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, postgresql

I was installing postgres on Ubuntu 18.04

the command line I used for installation is:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

since I have entered this command line a couple of times, I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgresql is already the newest version (10+190ubuntu0.1).
postgresql-contrib is already the newest version (10+190ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

as the result.

Things seem to be fine for now.

Then I tried to set the password for "postgres" by using:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

This is what I got:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

To tackle this problem I tried the following approaches:

1. To find out what processes are running as user postgres, I entered:

   ps -u postgres -f

and here is what I got:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

I don't quite understand what they are and how important they are. It would be kinda nice if you could tell me. With that being said, I didn't get much clue from this info.

2. I assume I haven't start postgresql yet due to this error:

   psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

so I tried:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

What I got:

```
[ ok ] Starting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.
```

Seems I got something there. So I ran:

```
psql
```

But the same error showed up:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

At this moment, I am really confused if I have started my postgres? If I have, why is "psql" not working. If I haven't, what else does this error indicate?

Then I tried an alternative setup approach:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

check "Alternative Server Setup" from the link. The link per se is pretty neat. However the following command lines didn't work for me:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
```

I got:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

OK, let me connect to db postgres:

For your reference:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postgresql-remote-access-or-connection/

1. Use the command line below to allow remote IP address to access PostgreSQL:

   su - postgres

I got:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

2.Allow communication over TCP/IP. I think this part is pretty important.

command line:

```
vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

I inserted this line to the interface:
host all all 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 trust

I used ":wq" to save and quit, but this was what I got:

```
"/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf"
"/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I had to close the terminal. I didn't know other ways to quit in this case.

It's the same thing here for:

```
$ vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

and

```
tcpip_socket = true
```

Just a bit more info:(cl:command line, fb:feedback)

1. cl:

   ps aux | grep postgres

fb:

```
ubuntu    5599  0.0  0.0  21536  1004 pts/1    S+   23:15   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

2. cl:

   sudo apt install postgres

fb:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgres
```

3. cl:

   sudo apt-get install postgres

fb:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgres
```

4.
When I use "sudo -i -u postgres" and type in "psql"
I got nothing different.

Yeah, that's pretty much it.

Will allowing communication over TCP/IP makes my "pqsl" work? If so, how do I save and quit?

Comment: You cannot use psql as long as PostgreSQL (PG) instance is not started.
Check which instances are installed with `pg_lsclusters`.  To start a cluster (or instance) try `sudo -u postgres pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluser> start`

Comment: I suggest to use more recent documentation for PG on Ubuntu than PG 9.3 which is about 7 years old: https://mydbanotebook.org/post/troubleshooting-01/

Comment: Apparently your server is failing to start.  This is out of the ordinary, as I've done this dozens of times without problem.  Look in the server log file (probably `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log`) to see if it has anything useful to say.